# mongo db update subdocument - subdocument not in array

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I have a document like this,

```
{
    "S" : {
        "500209" : {
            "total_income" : 38982,
            "interest_income" : 1714,
            "reported_eps" : 158.76,
            "year" : 201303
        }
    },
    "_id" : "pl"
}
```

I am trying to update this document like this,

```
{
    "S" : {
        "500209" : {
            "total_income" : 38982,
            "interest_income" : 1714,
            "reported_eps" : 158.76,
            "year" : 201303,
            "yield": 1001,  <== inserted a new attribute
        }
    },
    "_id" : "pl"
}
```

I have tried this,

```
db.my_collection.update({_id: 'pl'},{$set: {'S.500209.yield': 1}})
```

But I couldn't make it. And I searched in stack overflow and google but I couldn't find out.

I got so many answers but most of them keeping sub-docuemnts in array.

Pleas help me to solve my issue, and please tell me why most of them keeping subdocuments in array.

Answer (score 1):

Number key might cause the problem. Update your field name.

```
db.my_collection.update({_id: 'pl'},{$set: {'S.a500209.yield': 1}})
```

*EDIT*

Upgrade mongo version. It works fine with 2.4.

Comment: you are exactly correct. The problem is because of number. I have changed that number to a string and tried. It is working.

Comment: As I guess :) But the problem is definetely about numeric field name. S.500209 means that S is an array and I want 500209th element. Can you just add a prefix to your "500209" key and make it something like "a500209"? 'S.a500209.yield' would work, I think. If any solution without changing the field name is available, someone would enlighten us

Comment: I need a solution without changing field name :-) its hard for me to change field name.

Comment: I am using 2.2. Will upgrade it now ! Thanks a lot.